# Error when trying to run set on mac

Tags: scala, installation, sbt

I am trying to run sbt on my mac terminal. I keep getting this error message.

```
 java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
        at java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:34)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.locked(Launch.scala:238)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:147)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch.app(Launch.scala:145)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:102)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:35)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)
        at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:18)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:41)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:17)
        at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
    Error during sbt execution: java.io.IOException: No such file or directory
```

I read that it has to do with permission. But how do I change these permission so it works.

Answer (score 0):

SBT needs to be able to manage/write the user directories `~/.ivy`, `~/.sbt`, and the `project` subdir inside the directory where you run `sbt` command.